# How to read location coordinates of MODIS HDF file with Python GDAL?

Tags: python, hdf5, gdal, pyhdf

I am trying to read a MODIS HDF file with Python. I have used GDAL and pyhdf libraries. However, I am unsure why GDAL is unable to read location coordinates whereas pyhdf can read the same easily.
Following is the simple python code.

```
from pyhdf import SD
from osgeo import gdal

filename = 'MYD04_3K.A2016001.0310.061.2018059005952.hdf'

gdal_ds= gdal.Open(filename)
hdf_ds = SD.SD(filename)
print (hdf_ds.datasets())

for path, desc in file.GetSubDatasets():
    print(desc)
```

The output for pyhdf is as follows:

```
{'Longitude': (('Cell_Along_Swath:mod04', 'Cell_Across_Swath:mod04'), (676, 451), 5, 0), 'Latitude': (('Cell_Along_Swath:mod04', 'Cell_Across_Swath:mod04'), (676, 451), 5, 1), 'Scan_Start_Time': (('Cell_Along_Swath:mod04', 'Cell_Across_Swath:mod04'), (676, 451), 6, 2), 'Solar_Zenith': (('Cell_Along_Swath:mod04', 'Cell_Across_Swath:mod04'),
```

The output for GDAL is as follows:

```
[676x451] Solar_Zenith mod04 (16-bit integer)
[676x451] Solar_Azimuth mod04 (16-bit integer)
```

I would like to learn why GDAL is unable to read location coordinates here. Is there anything I'm missing? How can I extract the location information by using GDAL library? My main aim eventually is to plot a specific variable from HDF file on map.

Comment: It's a swath, so still an irregular grid (without any projection). There are tie-points (GCP's) in the metadata, so you could use those with `gdalwarp` to transform it to a regular grid. But those probably are low accuracy and you'll get better results to use the matching geolocation file (something like MYD03* for example (?), that should contain the latitude/longitude arrays with coordinates for every pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Check lines from 1952 to 1954 in

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/hdf4/hdf4imagedataset.cpp

pyhdf doesn't look for lat/lon datasets. It's a simple wrapper for HDF4 library.